# Getting Permission error java.lang.SecurityException: When Opening the Gmail Attachment in my App

Tags: android, gmail

I want to open the Gmail Attachment into my app. When I click on the Gmail Attachment it show my application. I set the intent filter for this. But When I click on the app I'm getting this exception 'Getting Permission error java.lang.SecurityException:'. Please look to resolve this.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.ACCESS_PROVIDER" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.email.permission.READ_ATTACHMENT" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.WRITE_GMAIL"/>
```

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` add this and try

Comment: I've already that permission in the AndroidManifest.xml. I only copied which I added to resolve this Security option to read the attachment from the Gmail